# ROW_NUMBER() OVER() partitioning at an odd place

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table with the following information:

```
Header 1 | Header 2 | Desired Column
    1    |    1     |      2
    2    |    1     |      3
    3    |    1     |   /  1
    1    |    2     |      2
    2    |    2     |      3
    3    |    2     |   /  1
    1    |    3     |      2
    2    |    3     |      3
    3    |    3     |   /  1
```

I'm trying to use `Row_Number() Over(Partition by)` to get the desired column you can see. I need the Row_number to be partitioned by Header 2, but by an odd number of header 1. If that makes sense? The backslashes indicate where I want the partition to be, and I want to be able to select which number in header 1 I want to partition by.

I tried to use Lag, but I can't make it work.

I also tried this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Header1 = 3, Header2) OVER (ORDER BY Header2, Header1)
```

Hope you understand, and that someone can find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
row_number() over(partition by header2 order by header1 % 2 desc, header1 desc)
```

This puts uneven `header1`s first, and then sorts by descending `header1`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f941310de5dc38922a3f23360359089)**:

```
Header1 | Header2 | rn
------: | ------: | -:
      1 |       1 |  2
      2 |       1 |  3
      3 |       1 |  1
      1 |       2 |  2
      2 |       2 |  3
      3 |       2 |  1
      1 |       3 |  2
      2 |       3 |  3
      3 |       3 |  1
```